# Jenkins Deploy Master Or Tagged Branch to Production

Tags: git, jenkins

I have been working on a internal project for my company, I have been learning git and Jenkins during this. I have 2 branches, develop and master. I deploy develop to a develop server and test until I am happy.  I then merge develop to master and tag the release with semantic versioning(v1.0.0).

The question I have is, when I want to release the code to the production servers, should I deploy the tagged branch(refs/tags/v1.0.0) or master branch.  Is there a best practice or an argument of which one is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Continuous Delivery practices you need to follow **build once - deploy everywhere** rule:

1. During the Build step on CI server you create a binary. Then you deploy it to whatever servers you need for testing.
2. After everything is tested you deploy *the same binary* that was tested. You *do not* create yet another binary from another branch with another version.

Otherwise there's a risk that what you tested and what you released to PRD are different binaries. The risk is usually small, but it's real. Usually it comes from poor configuration of CI jobs (proper configuration is actually not that easy), but it also can come from changes in the server that manages dependencies (for Java these are Nexus, Artifactory) or upgrades on the CI server.

So you shouldn't create a new build from the tag or master. Though you could get rid of the develop branch and work directly in master - this way you would release from master. Tagging will still be an option if needed.

Comment: I am following the Atlassian git flow model where develop and master are maintained. If I am testing the develop branch then I merge the develop branch to master, in theory it would be an exact replica.  I am deploying python via Jenkins so no binary release is necessary.  I am learning git tagging and was not sure on what I release to the production server(master/git tagged branch).  I guess I am still not fully understanding tagging, I know its a point in time that freezes the repo state.  So one would think that would be what you want to deploy, however I have not found much documentation.

Comment: GitFlow is a very(!) outdated way of branching. I'm not even sure if it was up-to-date with the modern practices when it was originally described. And even if you were to follow GitFlow (which you should read from the original article instead of reading Atlassian: https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) you'd release from a `release` branch, _then_ merge it to `master`. As for the tags - they are just pointers to the commits. Same as branches (but branches move from commit to commit while tags stay stationary). Tags/branches are not as important - commits, blobs, trees are.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to have a link to a modern way of branching / deploying that I could follow, does a link like that even exist? Or is that learned over time?

Comment: CI/CD suggests so called Trunk-Based development, there's plenty of good materials on the internet, pay attention to Branching by Abstraction & Feature Toggles. It may be too extreme at the beginning, but try it out. You can read the original book on CD (though it's very repetitive and thus a bit boring): https://www.amazon.com/Continuous-Delivery-Deployment-Automation-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321601912